# Are "Share" messages logged in JIRA, and can I search them?

Tags: jira

Last week, I sent a message via JIRA's "Share" link on one issue to a requester with nearly 100 issues. I haven't received a response and want to follow up, but I don't remember which issue it was. Are "Share" messages logged in JIRA, and is it possible for me to search them? It would be nice to not have to go back through each individual list and search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you shared the JIRA by click the Share icon on top right, then it's only sending an email, you have no way to trace back which issue you shared from JIRA.
If you shared the issue by mentioning user's name in comment or description, you can check your activities stream for issues you have edited.